# Redirect to 404page if link found broken

Tags: java, jsp

I want the user of my website to land in 404.jsp if some link appears to be broken. For example, I have an index.jsp where there are several links. Now If any link is not found, then the server should redirect to the 404.jsp
I don't think
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=/next/page/to/go/to.jsp">`
can be used in this context. How shall I perform this task?

Comment: If it's only internal links to the web site, this is something that can usually be configured on your server. If it's to external web sites, I don't think you can do much other than testing the link at the server side and dynamically redirecting. In any event, this is more a question for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter for that in your application's `web.xml` config file :

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>404</exception-type>
   <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If the user requests any resource that does not exist, she will be redirected to the given error page.

Comment: This code helped me in what I wantd to do. Just I didnt use the xception type to make it general.

 <error-page>
  <location>/404.jsp</location>
 </error-page>